# Questions about the sketch of the proof : every Projective variety is complete

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I cannot understand the following sketch of the proof: Every projective variety is complete using [Nakayama Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nakayama%27s_lemma).
[The following lecture note on the 279 pages](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5aff705c5ffd207cc87a512d/t/5cffefb4715045000138e4b9/1560276924431/Algebraic+Geometry.pdf) is one recently
that I have referred.

[image]

To show this, the lecturer defines the set

$$\mathcal{V}^{*}(I):=\left \{ (x^{*},y) \in \mathbb{P}^n \times Y : f(x^{*},y)=0 \right \}, $$

and since it is a closed set, then it is sufficient to show that $\pi(\mathcal{V}^{*}(I))$ is closed, or equivalently, $\overline{\pi(\mathcal{V}^{*}(I)) }=\pi(\mathcal{V}^{*}(I)) $...... (★).

To begin with, in my thoughts, (★) seems to hold: $\mathcal{V}^{*}(I) $ is closed, i.e consists of finite elements, and its projection is also finite on $Y$ whose topology is Zariski topology, so $\pi(\mathcal{V}^{*}(I)) $ is still closed.

However, the author also said "*we must show for every $y \in Y$, there exists $x^{*} \in \mathbb{P}^n$ so that $(x^{*},y) \in \mathcal{V}^{*}(I) $*".
In my thoughts, the author seems to verify that $\mathcal{V}^{*}(I)$ is a nonempty set, and to ascertain this, the author takes a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m} \subset A $ that vanishes at $y$, and sets $J:=\mathfrak{m}B+I $.

Then he says "*if $\mathcal{V}^{*}(J)$ is non-empty, we'll be done*" (I understand this paragraph is an alternative way of showing that  $\mathcal{V}^{*}(I) \neq \phi$).
Here the author uses Nakayama's Lemma in order to verify $\mathcal{V}^{*}(J)\neq 0$.

I have some questions regarding the proof.

1. I am little confused on the statement that $\mathcal{V}^{*}(I)$ is closed in $\mathbb{P}^n \times Y$. I believe **that it is also closed in the Zariski topology.** Since the product topology is the weakest topology (or initial topology), then the product of the Zariski topology is stronger than box topology. **Is this the right idea?** Anyway, if we take $\mathcal{V}^{*}(I)$ in the Zariski topology, then it is closed in $\mathbb{P}^n \times Y$ because  $\mathcal{V}^{*}(I)$ is a finite set.
2. The author showed that $\mathcal{V}^{*}(J)\neq \phi$ (As I said, by guesswork, I firmly believe that this is an alternative proof of  $\mathcal{V}^{*}(I)\neq \phi $).
   He proved this by contradiction: assuming that $\mathcal{V}^{*}(J)= \phi$, the author induces $\mathcal{V}^{*}(I)= \phi$. I can indirectly infer this by Nakayama's Lemma:  $J=\mathfrak{m}B+I $ implies $J=I$ where $I$ is a submodule of a finitely generated $A$-module.
   Hence $$\phi=\mathcal{V}^{*}(J) \underset{Nakyama }{=} \mathcal{V}^{*}(I).$$
   He then gives the contradiction *"but it is impossible for a proper ideal $I \subset B$"*.
   **I do not understand why the author carried out the proof by applying Nakayama's Lemma, defining the set $J$ etc.**, because since $I$ is a proper ideal of $B$, the relation $\mathcal{V}^{*}(I)\neq \phi $ is always satisfied.
   I have tried reasoning it out as follows:

> It must be that $\mathcal{V}^{*}(I)\neq \phi$, since $\mathcal{V}^{*}(I)= \phi$ is
> impossible for a proper ideal $I \subset B$. Hence,
> $\mathcal{V}^{*}(I)\neq \phi$.

Comment: For (1), it seems as though the author is taking the topology on $\mathbb{P}^n \times Y$ to be the product of the Zariski topology, so effectively by definition the $\mathcal{V}^*(U)$ are the closed sets of $\mathbb{P}^n \times Y$.

Comment: I think that I misunderstood the notation... Largely, the notation of (closed set of) Zariski topology is deonted by$ V(I)$, but I viewed $\mathcal{V}^∗(I)$ as a "new" notation at the time. It is trivially closed set by defintion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's outline how the proof is supposed to go first - parts of your questions are based on misconceptions about the strategy. The idea is that we need to show that for any $Y$ and any nonempty closed $C\subset \Bbb P^n\times Y$, the image of $C$ in $Y$ under the projection is closed. So we want to consider the minimal possible situation: shrink $Y$ so that $Y=\overline{\pi(C)}$, therefore checking whether $\pi(C)$ is closed amounts to checking that $C\to \overline{\pi(C)}$ surjective. This is because $\overline{\pi(C)}$ is the smallest closed subset containing $\pi(C)$, so $\pi(C)$ is closed iff $\pi(C)=\overline{\pi(C)}$.

To show that $\pi(C)=\overline{\pi(C)}$, it's enough to show that there's a point of $C$ in the fiber $\pi^{-1}(y)$ for all $y\in Y=\overline{\pi(C)}$. Writing $C$ as $\mathcal{V}^*(I)$ for some choice of homogeneous ideal $I\subset B$, $\mathcal{V}^*(J)$ is the intersection of $\mathcal{V}^*(I)$ with the fiber $\pi^{-1}(y)$ - the strategy of the proof is to show that if $\mathcal{V}^*(J)$ is empty, then $\mathcal{V}^*(I)$ must be as well, which will be a contradiction because we took $C=\mathcal{V}^*(I)$ to be nonempty.

---

Aside from the issues addressed above, your post has some other misconceptions I believe should be corrected. Here goes:

> To begin with, in my thoughts, (★) seems to hold: $\mathcal{V}^{*}(I) $ is closed, i.e consists of finite elements, and its projection is also finite on $Y$ whose topology is Zariski topology, so $\pi(\mathcal{V}^{*}(I)) $ is still closed.

Yes, $\mathcal{V}^*(I)$ is closed, but this business about "finite elements" does not make sense (what even are "finite elements"?). If you knew that the projection $\pi(\mathcal{V}^{*}(I))$ to $Y$ were closed, you would be done: every closed subset of $\Bbb P^n\times Y$ is of this form. You're getting ahead of yourself here.

> 1. I am little confused on the statement that $\mathcal{V}^{*}(I)$ is closed in $\mathbb{P}^n \times Y$. I believe **that it is also closed in the Zariski topology.** Since the product topology is the weakest topology (or initial topology), then the product of the Zariski topology is stronger than box topology. **Is this the right idea?** Anyway, if we take $\mathcal{V}^{*}(I)$ in the Zariski topology, then it is closed in $\mathbb{P}^n \times Y$ because  $\mathcal{V}^{*}(I)$ is a finite set.

When we consider the product of varieties, we put the Zariski topology on it, not the product topology. The statement that "$\mathcal{V}^{*}(I)$ is closed in $\mathbb{P}^n \times Y$" is taking $\Bbb P^n\times Y$ to have the Zariski topology. I do not understand why you think " $\mathcal{V}^{*}(I)$ is a finite set" - this is false and you should let go of this belief. Consider  $Y=\Bbb A^2$ and $n=1$, so $B=k[t_1,t_0][x_0,x_1]$ with $x_0,x_1$ homogeneous of degree one and $t_0,t_1$ homogeneous of degree zero. Then $\mathcal{V}^*((t_0))$ is a copy of $\Bbb P^1\times\Bbb A^1$ which is not finite.

Comment: I understand the sketch of proof to some extent. Remaining question on your answer is why $\mathcal{V}^{∗} (J)$ is the intersection of  $\mathcal{V}^{∗} (I)$ with the fiber $\pi^{−1}(y)$.

Comment: Look at the definition - $J$ is the sum of the ideal of $I$ with the ideal of the fiber. By the inclusion-reversing bijection between ideals and algebraic subsets, this means that $J$ is the largest closed set contained in both the fiber and $\mathcal{V}^*(I)$, which is exactly their intersection.